# Getting an image URL from a message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to get the image URL or the image itself from a message, and put it in my embed. I have no idea to do it myself, hope you can help me :)

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user, message) => {
const eggsa = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "eggsa");
if (reaction.emoji.name === 'eggsa') {
  const msg = reaction.message;
  const guild = msg.guild;
  const guildMembers = guild.members;
  const guildMember = guildMembers.get(user.id);
  if (!guildMember.roles.some(r=>["Leder"].includes(r.name)) ) return guildMember.send(" ',:^\\ ");
    const message = reaction.message;
    const kanal = reaction.message.guild.channels.find('name', 'sitater');
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(message.author.username, reaction.message.author.avatarURL)
    .setImage()
    kanal.send({embed});
}
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you give us some more details please. Is it a normal text message in a guild textchannel or is it a RichEmbed? Is the message only a url with an image or is there also other text in and you want to find where the url is? ... Answers on this questions would help us to help you! :)

Comment: Its a normal text message in a guild textchannel, and there would be text and an image attached to the message. The image would be normally just uploaded directly to discord so there would be no direct link. I want it to recreate the message as a richEmbed, so it would have a quote feel. Hope this helps and ty :) https://imgur.com/IMXDv9Y i want it to look something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `.attachments` property from the message object. This returns you all attachments of this message included all pictures. From there on, you can use the property `.url` and this gives you the image url that you can add in your embed.

In the following code I added a check if there are even attachments. If yes, add the first image url as image of the embed.

Here is the code:

```
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user, message) => {
    const eggsa = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'eggsa');
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'eggsa') {
        const msg = reaction.message;
        const guild = msg.guild;
        const guildMembers = guild.members;
        const guildMember = guildMembers.get(user.id);
        if (!guildMember.roles.some(r => ['Leder'].includes(r.name))) return guildMember.send(" ',:^\\ ");
        const message = reaction.message;
        const kanal = reaction.message.guild.channels.find('name', 'sitater');
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(message.content)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(message.author.username, reaction.message.author.avatarURL);

        if (message.attachments.size !== 0) {
            embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url);
        }

        kanal.send({ embed });
    }
});
```

Comment: It crashes when i add the emoji to a message and can you help me show the erros

Comment: Does the emoji event exist? Try to remove this line of this emoji because that's another question. Try to test the code with the message.attachments please @blydex

Comment: err: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: I fixed an issue in my code. Can you try it again please @blydex

Comment: it works only when the message has an image, and not if it have just text

Comment: Try to use it again please @blydex

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for this issues that were still in the code